# The meaning behind most of the dirent arguments

Tags: c, file, directory, dirent.h

I'm having some difficulty understanding the meaning behind all this parameters in the dirent structure.

```
struct dirent{
        ino_t           d_ino;      Inode number
        off_t           d_off;      Not an offset; see below
        unsigned short  d_reclen;   Length of this record
        unsigned chart  d_type;     Type of file; 
                                    not supported by all filesystem types

        char            d_name[256]; Null-Terminated filename
    }
```

I really need to understand this because I have to work on some files.
Correct if I'm wrong, this struct is returned when you use opendir on a DIR* object right?
This object is non-other than metadata of the file inside the directory, and every time I use it will return me the metadata of the next file, right?

The parameters that I don't understand are:
d_off -> not an offset? What is it then? See below where? I checked the original page with all the info and I couldn't find where was I supposed to look.
d_type -> what do they mean with "not supported by all filesystem types"? Which filesystem should I look out for?
Okay, with this information how can I open the file on which I have to modify the data?
Do I just use the d_name, or is there something way more comfortable I can rely on?
Those are all my doubts, thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you read [this](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html)? Anyway the only field you need to deal with is `d_name`, the others are useless in most cases.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. Yeah, I read the beginning but I couldn't find the see below part, now I found it.

Answer (score 1):

The only two members of that struct that are guaranteed to exist as per posix are `d_name` and `d_ino`.([Source](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/dirent.h.html))

In other words you should ignore the other struct members, and only use the following standard functions to manipulate `dirent` structs.

Comment: I see, good to know thanks, is the inode number only useful to compare two symbolic pointers (e.g. to check if they are pointing at the same file?)

Comment: @B.Castarunza afaik yes.

Answer (score 1):

The POSIX standard only defines the structure to have [`d_ino` and `d_name`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/dirent.h.html).  The remaining structure fields are [Linux specific](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html).

The Linux manual page says that `d_off` is related to the [`telldir`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/telldir.3.html) function, and that it should be considered an opaque value.

In short, you should never need to read or otherwise use this member.

As for the `d_type` member, its meaning and values is well-documented in [the Linux manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html). On any normal filesystem it should be valid.

Comment: If I'm exploring a directory with opendir, is it normal that the files are read in a random order? I have a directory with n files each named *File_i*, where *i* is a number between *0 and n*, but the order in which I print out their name is consistent but casual, what I mean is that the order is: "FIle1 FIle7 File6 File3 ecc . . ." and every time I run the program the same order is outputted. I only use one process to run it.

Comment: @B.Castarunza Could be ordered by inode number? If you want any specific ordering you need to collect all file-names, order them in the way you want, and then print in that order.